# SAPUI5: set Timepicker configuration for 15 min interval

Tags: sapui5

Is is possible to configure the `sap.m.TimePicker` to display only 15 minute intervals?

At the moment the user can enter any time they like.

Comment: Also, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323126/merging-tags-sapui5-and-sapui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible now with version 1.40.+ 
There was incorrect information in the API documentation and it wasn't possible even on version 1.38

Answer (score 0):

Change it to a DropDownBox with a value range of 00:00, 00:15, 00:30, ... 23:30, 23:45? This makes the limitation to specific intervals clear at a glance, is easy to implement and avoids entry of undesired values altogether.

Comment: This does work, but it's ugly. I would much rather use the sap.m.time picker if that's possible

Answer (score 0):

While @vwegert 's answer is function I think there is a better way where you you still get the look and feel of the TimePicker.

In the [source of the control](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/TimePicker.js) there is a property `minutesStep`. If you can set this in the xml or js definition I think you could be onto a winner.

In fact there is a setter (yay) `setMinutesStep`.

`oTimer.setMinutesStep(15);` should be a winner for you.

Hope that helps, 
Nigel

Comment: Many thanks Nigel. This would be the ideal solution for me, but I've updated my XML view and it's ignoring minutesStep. Do I need the latest version of SAP?

Comment: You need 1.32 as a minimum to have timepicker aside from that I haven't looked if minutesStep has been added later. Interestingly it is not in the lastest SDK doc but is used in the lastest tests for Timepicker I saw. I will keep digging for you.:)

Comment: Here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/sopune/edit?html,js,output) that trys to replicate it but in the xml or the javascript it doesnt work. :(

Comment: I know, that's really disappointing. I may be forced into going down the select / dropdown box route unfortunately.

Comment: Interestingly the 1.32 version doesn't have this [property](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.32/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/TimePicker.js) and looking closer in the codebase it is only introduced in the master branch so it is probably coming to 1.38 when it is released later this year.